# Wordpress, getting query from sql database and echoing it

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress

I want to get post last modification/craetion dates by particular users and then echo it.

What I'm trying to do is:

```
<?php $id = get_the_ID();               

global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$postID = $id;  //assigning post id
$userID = $current_user->ID;  // assigning user ID

$sql = "SELECT post_date FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = $postID AND post_author = $userID ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1";
$userModifiedDate = $wpdb->query($sql);
echo $userModifiedDate; ?>
```

Where is my mistake? Can anyone lead me through this?

At the moment `$userModifiedDate` returns me `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$wpdb->query()` returns the number of rows affected rather than the actual query result.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Run_Any_Query_on_the_Database

Try using a more specific function such as `$wpdb->get_var()` or `$wpdb->get_results()`:

```
$userModifiedDate = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Variable

Also, while it's not *absolutely* necessary, I always like to pass any queries through `$wpdb->prepare()` first:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_date FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = %d AND post_author = %d ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1", $postID, $userID );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks

Comment: Thank you very much, needed to tweek it a little bit, but that helped me a lot! :)